# importing csv files to R

Tags: r, csv

I imported csv.file to software R. But, when listing the data in R, variable names and variable values are not separated. (Screenshot is posted ~ picture1) Also, when seeing the variable names, variables name is listed in one column as if it is one name. (picture2) There is a problem. I need to separate them. How to solve it? Thank you so much.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not a csv. Use `read.table(...,sep=";")` Further, your header has a different separating value than your data. If you change the periods in your header to semi-colons the `read.table()` will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read.csv` splits data by `,` and your file has `;`. Try `read.csv2` instead.